# 2004 Toyota tarago accelerator not working

Tags: electrical, toyota

I have a 2004 Toyota tarago & put a new battery in it but didn't realise it was around the wrong way & I connected the terminals back to front (negative to positive, positive to negative) for only a couple seconds, I found 1 blown fuse which was for the ECU which I replaced. I can start the car & it will idle, I can put it in drive & reverse but as soon as I touch the accelerator there is nothing, accelerator not working at all but motor will still idle, when put it in drive or reverse the car will move under the power of idle, i have read many different things on what it might be online, throttle position sensor, air flow sensor or there might be a relay that's crapped itself.
If anyone can help me with what it might be would be great, thanks

Comment: In the engine bay can you find the throttle body air intake valve and push on that to make the engine rev higher?

Comment: My problem is the engine won't rev at all, a friend suggested i clean the air flow sensor & replace throttle body sensor, do u know where the air intake valve is? Is it with the throttle body sensor?

Comment: I think what your friend is suggesting you look at is the "Throttle Position Sensor" (TPS), which is where I'd look as well. The TPS tells the ECU how fast you want the engine to go. If you open the throttle, there's a big rush of air, yet the computer doesn't adjust for this (doesn't give it more gas), it'll kill the engine as the engine will go into a huge lean state. Too much air and not enough fuel and you get a stalled engine.